# Upgrade URL not working. Drupal7

Tags: drupal, upgrade

I have civicrm on a local server using Drupal7. 
I have had the same issue with every recent upgrade.
The SysAdmin manual contains the following url to update the database following an upgrade:
http://example.org/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1

In my case I am using a local fileserver so this becomes:
http://myserver/drupal/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1
This has not worked for me on a number of upgrades which resulted in me finding a different method by mistake. (honesty).
The url I have now used successfully is :
http://myserver/drupal/index.php?q=civicrm/upgrade?reset=1

suggesting the following generic url
http://example.org/index.php?q=civicrm/upgrade?reset=1

So my question is whether there is an error in my original install which is causing the documented url not to work?

Answer (score 3):

Your local server probably isn't configured in a way to allow for "clean urls". See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/configuring-clean-urls/enable-clean-urls

Comment: Clean URLs are not enabled so thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: You'll find most examples assume Clean URLs is enabled.  They are though just a simpler representation of the format you posted above.